# How to get StackTrace of called Assert?

Tags: c#, exception, assert, stack-trace

I can get StackTrace for Exception. But I don't know how to get StackTrace for Assert. How to find out in which method Assert was called?

My code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
 
    class MyProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] agrs)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceException!;
 
            var foo = new Foo();
 
            try
            {
                foo.FuncException();
            }
            catch { }
 
            try
            {
                foo.FuncAssert();
            }
            catch { }
 
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException -= FirstChanceException!;
        }
 
        static private void FirstChanceException(object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs firstChanceExceptionEventArgs)
        {
            var ex = firstChanceExceptionEventArgs.Exception;
            if (ex != null)
                Console.WriteLine($" * * * \n Message: {ex.Message} \n StackTrace: {GetStackTrace(ex)} \n");
        }
 
        static private string GetStackTrace(Exception ex)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
 
            var trace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
            foreach (var frame in trace.GetFrames())
            {
                list.Add($"{frame.GetMethod()?.ReflectedType?.Name}.{frame.GetMethod()?.Name}");
            }
 
            return string.Join(" -> ", list);
        }
 
        public class Foo
        {
            public void FuncException()
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception - FuncException");
            }
 
            public void FuncAssert()
            {
                Assert.Fail("Assert - FuncAssert");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If Assert fails, you StackTrace should be displayed in the test results

Comment: @maxc137
please see my example code here: https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2945444.html

Comment: @VladDX please see my example code here: cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2945444.html

Comment: I see your code but don't understand what you are trying to do. Why do you want to do it via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you put your code to the question please? The code is a part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You register an event handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceException;
```

2. You call `Assert.Fail()`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void FuncAssert()
    {
        Assert.Fail("Assert - FuncAssert");
    }
}
```

I assume that you expect to see the whole call stack in the exception. But call stack is only gathered when exception is bubbling through the stack.

And `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` catches the exception right in the place where it's thrown.

> Occurs when an exception is thrown in managed code, before the runtime searches the call stack for an exception handler in the application domain.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception

So, I would say that you are trying to do something wrong.

**What is the problem that you are actually trying to solve?**

This code will work well because I let exception to bubble along the call stack and be caught:

```
try
{
    foo.FuncAssert();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" * * * \n Message: {ex.Message} \n StackTrace: {GetStackTrace(ex)} \n");
}
```

> **Output**:
>
> Message: Assert - FuncAssert
>
> StackTrace: Assert.ReportFailure -> Assert.Fail -> Assert.Fail -> Foo.FuncAssert -> MyProgram.Main

Comment: Wrapping the Assert in a try-catch doesn't look good.

Comment: @Mr.Kama, I don't understand what is the problem that you are actually trying to solve?